# Why can not we use Lagrange multiplier in mathematical (in particular linear) programming?

Tags: linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

I am studying linear programming right now. And I can not explain to myself why I can not solve any linear programming task using the Lagrange multiplier method.

Could you help me understand that, please?

Comment: Can you elaborate how you are going to do it in more detail?

Comment: Keep studying LP- you'll find that Lagrange multipliers do appear (with the new name of "dual variables.")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic method of Lagrange multipliers only works for maximizing over a set given by a system of equations. Any interesting linear program, on the other hand, will contain some inequalities, even if it's only the domain constraints of the form $x \ge 0$.

In a multivariable calculus class, you might learn to use Lagrange polynomials to deal with inequalities by doing casework: to deal with an inequality $ax \le b$, you can either set $ax=b$, or ignore the inequality and later check if it's satisfied. This corresponds to the "brute force" approach to linear programming, where we check all possible intersections of the inequalities and find which vertex is optimal.

You may have also seen the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker method, which generalizes the method of Lagrange multipliers to deal with inequalities. It can indeed be used to solve linear programs: it corresponds to using the dual linear program and complementary slackness to find a solution.

The special case of linear programming, however, is much nicer than the general case of the KKT method for solving nonlinear programs. It is better to first learn linear programming, and then see what features of the method do and do not extend to nonlinear programming.

Comment: `Any interesting linear program, on the other hand, will contain some inequalities` It is not a problem to move from inequalities to equalities. For example, if we have $\leq$ we can add a bogus positive variable to have an equality.

Comment: @hellohowdoyoudo The key word in your sentence is "positive": you will still need an inequality to enforce that your bogus variable is $\ge 0$. We still often introduce these variables, because it's convenient to only have *one* kind of inequality; however, you can't get rid of inequalities entirely.

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Comment: So, the only difference between Lagrange multiplier method and mathematical programming is that in the latter we can have inequalities, while in the former we can have only equalities. Am I getting it correct?

Comment: The other major difference is that while we can optimize over all systems of equations with Lagrange multipliers, we need additional conditions to optimize over systems of inequalities. (See Wikipedia on the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).) So only some classes of problems can be solved in this way. (For example, the first condition, LCQ, is the condition saying that we can solve linear programs.)

Comment: Is it correct to say that Lagrange (KKT) method is applicable to all LP problems, however in large instances (multiple variables and constraints) it's inefficient?

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a good answer- inequalities are not the issue - I believe the issue is because we cannot enforce decision variables to be positive

Answer (score -1):

I cannot give a complete answer, but I believe the accepted answer is not accurate.

Inequalities are not the issue - linear programs with inequalities are converted to equalities using slack and surplus variables.

I believe the issue is because we cannot enforce decision variables to be positive, using Lagrange. The principle advancement made by the Simplex method was to ensure positive values for decision variables, which is imperative for the algorithm to produce meaningful results.

Without enforcing positivity, one variable can shoot way positive and another variable can shoot way negative. As an example, given this:

```
x + y = 1;
```

we want something like 0.3 and 0.7, but with a smooth system we could get (-139393 + 139394), or literally **any** combination.

You might think, well we could solve this with slack variables:

x >= 0;
y >= 0;

which translates to:

```
x - s1 = 0;
y - s2 = 0;
```

but then we are back to ***square one***, because we need to enforce s1 and s2 to be positive.

*note that in reality, by positive, we really mean non-negative, since variables can take on value of 0 in Simplex algorithms.

Comment: I think you missed my point. Nonnegativity constraints *are also inequalities*.

Comment: Your answer is misleading at best, just be honest with yourself for a second. If what you mean by inequalities is "non-negativity constraints on decision variables" then sure, but you need to edit your answer to make that more clear.

Comment: I *literally* mentioned "domain constraints of the form $x \ge 0$" in my answer.

Comment: Ok great, we can leave everything as is. The subtlety, is that in Simplex, it is not a formal constraint, it is an informal constraint, the algorithm simply does not visit negative values of decision variables.

Comment: You said "Nonnegativity constraints are also inequalities" - they are not the same, because in the Simplex algorithm, it's not a formal mathematical inequality - it's that the algorithm starts with a feasible non-negative point and never visits any negative values.

Comment: I know how the simplex method works. I have just finished teaching a semester-long class on how the simplex method works. What you're saying is more or less true (I would argue that it *is* a formal mathematical inequality, just one that the simplex method handles differently) but it is irrelevant to this question, which is asking about whether we can use *Lagrange multipliers* to solve linear programs, and those do not distinguish between these kinds of inequalities.

Comment: I think we are in agreement. I believe that Lagrange can solve almost all LPs, as there is some relationship between interior point algorithms and Lagrange methods. The difference has nothing to do with inequalities, because the equations are identical in both methods. Your answer is therefore misleading. Simplex and Lagrange/IPM operate on the same equations, but use a different algorithm. There are no inequalities when the algorithms start, just the same equations.

Comment: There *are* inequalities! If I tell you "maximize x subject to x+y=1" or "maximize x subject to x+y=1 with x,y>=0" then these are **two different problems**. You do not appear to understand this. Your answer is all about criticizing my answer for calling an inequality an inequality even though an unrelated algorithm treats that inequality in a special way. You are not really even answering the question that is actually being asked. (Anyway, I am bowing out of this discussion. Come back when your answer actually addresses Lagrange methods at all.)

Comment: Sorry for being critical, I am trying to be constructive. 

There are no inequalities, they are always converted to equalities with slack variables and surplus variables. Your very first sentence is "The basic method of Lagrange multipliers only works for maximizing over a set given by a system of equations." The same is true for Simplex, etc.